# PHP gettext() not translating strings

Tags: php, zend-framework, gettext

I am trying to implement gettext() for building a multi-lingual PHP web app.

Here's what I did:

1. Installed GNU gettext package in C:\Program Files
2. Installed POedit
3. Checked my php.ini file, and gettext was enabled

   `extension=php_gettext.dll`
4. Checked if gettext() is installed using function_exists()
5. Set folder structure : test-project/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/
6. Created the translation files using POedit
7. Checked translation files have been generated properly, i.e., messages.po and messages.mo

I was following this tutorial: https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/

Here's my .po file:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-06-09 15:45+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-06-09 17:07+0530\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.2\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_US\n"

# Test1
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "Hallo"
```

Here's my .php file

```
$language = "en_US";
putenv("LANG=".$language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

//Set the text domain as messages
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
textdomain($domain);

echo gettext("Hello");
```

Any kind of help would be appreciable.